# CoffeeScript в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Здравствуйте. Объясните на пальцах мне насчет этих двух языков.

Как я понял, когда я пишу минималистский код на `CS` и компилирую его, то я что, получаю огромный код на `JS`? А потом его можно внедрять на сайт?

Comment: Все правильно поняли. CS просто "компилируется" в JS, заменяя синтаксис более "сладким" (см. [синтаксический сахар](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80))

Comment: Тогда уж может лучше roy http://brianmckenna.org/ ?

Answer (score 3):

`CoffeeScript` написали для рубистов, которые ниасилили `JavaScript`, рекомендую на заморачиваться по этому поводу и учить js

Да, в нём есть определённые плюшки как `List comprehension`, недетерминированная обработка данных, `String interpolation` и `"Everything is expression"`, но аналогичные вещи либо уже есть в `Javascript 1.8`, либо скоро появится, либо просто не нужны

> **UPD:** т.к. cs создавали для рубистов, то философию руби чуток переняли, особенно, что касается возможности сделать одно и тоже действие разными способами, что позволяет недетерминировання обработка данных, а т.к. разные программисты будут следовать разным стилям, то разбирать их код будет в разы сложнее, поэтому.

к тому же наличие всяких `or, and, not` и при этом возможность использования канонические `&&, ||, !` делает код избыточным и похожим на ужас:

```
@listen_to_changes() if !@_db_changes_enabled && ((@db and @db.changes) or con.config.global_changes)
```

и ни чем не лучше:

```
if (!this._db_changes_enabled && 
    ((this.db && this.db.changes) || con.config.global_changes)) {
  return this.listen_to_changes();
}
```

или для любителей однострочников:

```
(!this._db_changes_enabled && ((this.db && this.db.changes) || con.config.global_changes)) && this.listen_to_changes();
```

> примеры взяты из реального [проекта](https://github.com/janmonschke/backbone-couchdb/blob/master/backbone-couchdb.coffee)

а "безскобочный синтаксис" по-моему самое неудобное, что можно было придумать:

```
 a b c d
```

что это?

```
a(b(c(d)));
a(b(c)(d));
a(b)(c(d));
a(b(c))(d);
a(b)(c)(d);
```

Плюс ИМХО `Javascript 1.8` уже куда более круче, чем CS

---

P.S. учитывая, что я высказал достаточно спорное мнение, просьба высказывать [ваше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1797/ilya-pirogov) не только плюсами-минусами, но и комментариями

Comment: А все высокоуровневые языки придумали для тех, кто ниасилил ассемблер

Comment: движение от низкоуровневых языков к высокоуровневым - это прогресс, а от высокоуровневого к высокоуровневому - это что-то сомнительно выгодное

Comment: а я думал cs посмотреть как раз, спасибо, теперь выходные потрачу на что-то другое :)

Comment: > а от высокоуровневого к высокоуровневому - это что-то сомнительно выгодное
Ни разу. Препроцессоры придумали не вчера. Lisp с его макросами тоже. И, скажем, к C++ Вы как относитесь? Оно, исторически, первоначально транслировалось в C, потом уже сделали отдельный язык.

> a b c d — что это?
Документацию, сразу видно, не читали, но критикуете. `a(b(c(d)))`, разумеется, ничем иным это быть не может. Запятых ведь нет.

Comment: но всё что я описал на самом деле мелочи по сравнению с тем, что разбирать код на cs без знаний всех тонкостей транслятора крайне сложно, а разбирать транслируемый код, как ни странно ещё сложнее. С Lisp`ом и его макросами или плюсами разве также?

>a b c d — что это?

это я привёл для примера, что со скобками в cs такая же история как с точками с запятой в js - их можно опустить, но делать это нежелательно, поэтому смысл давать повод делать нежелательные действия? а Indentation как способ разделения кода на блоки, типа для приучения к порядку, вообще у меня в голове не укладывается

Comment: И на Пайтоне можно писать код, который будет сложно разобрать. Тут уж зависит от автора кода. Я, например, когда пишу на CS, стараюсь максимально приближать его к синтаксису Пайтона. Мне тоже не понравилась возможность писать вызовы функций скобок. Но никто же не заставляет писать так! Поэтому я - всегда пишу со скобками. Так явней.

Если в языке есть какая-то особенность - это не значит, что ее нужно юзать обязательно

Comment: > Если в языке есть какая-то особенность - это не значит, что ее нужно юзать обязательно

если у js есть такая возможность как писать его код на cs - это не значит, что её нужно юзать - квинтэссенция моего ответа

Comment: > и при этом возможность использования канонические

А вы не смешивайте их. `!`, `&&` и `||` это артефакт, оставленный, как я понимаю, для большой обратной совместимости (что, действительно, не нужно — из-за backticks).

> и ни чем не лучше

Лучше сигилом вместо `this`. В остальном, действительно, одно и то же, ибо калька. Для читаемости надо микро-рефакторинг.

> @db and @db.changes

Вообще-то, идиома — `@db?.changes`.

И структурно лучше, если бы `@db.changes` включало `@_db_changes_enabled` к себе под капот. Тогда все сведется к `@listen_to_changes if @db?.changes or config.global_changes`

Comment: > возможности сделать одно и тоже действие разными способами

Кстати, что именно кроме `and`/`&&`?

А как контрпример стоит вспомнить сколько «традиционных» (т.е. не основанных на прототипах, а «классическом» наследовании) объектных систем придумали для JS. Против одной в CS.

Comment: >Кстати, что именно кроме and/&&?

ваш комментарий, что выше, разве не пример? 

резюмируя, т.к. лимит комментариев исчерпан, CoffeScript не панация и не Silver Bullet, но приверженцам Python`а и Ruby облегчает жизнь, сторонникам js только усложняет, т.к. влечёт за собой нечитабельный код и холивары.

Comment: > С Lisp`ом и его макросами или плюсами разве также?

Везде так, даже у компиляторов C случались прорухи, когда приходилось лезть в объектный код и смотреть чего они там накомпилировали. И с макрами так же. Никогда крестовые ошибки с километровыми строчками шаблонов не декодировали?

> поэтому смысл давать повод делать нежелательные действия

Если посадить за разработку опытных производителей дрянь-кода, то они сделают дрянь на любом языке. Но CS это не Java, где все сделано, чтобы «чего не намудрили.» Подразумевается, что у разработчика есть не только руки, но и мозги и чувство меры.

Comment: > P.S. учитывая, что я высказал достаточно спорное мнение, просьба высказывать ваше не только плюсами-минусами, но и комментариями

А что тут комментировать? Ваше первое предложение весьма красноречиво говорит о вашем предвзятом отношении к CoffeeScript, поэтому диалога бы все равно не получилось.